# Dagger2 and external library: unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

In my android project I'm using an AAR library module that I've written, and both project and library use *Dagger* for dependency injection.

In my project I use library like this:

```
fun useLibrary() {
    startActivityForResult(
        Intent(
            this,
            LibraryActivity::class.java
        ),
        A_REQUEST_CODE
    )
}
```

but when I launch my app I got an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.android.myproject/com.mypackage.aMyLib.LibraryActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<com.mypackage.aMyLib.LibraryActivity>
```

EDIT

This is dagger code inside my library:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class,
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApp> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    override fun inject(application: MyApp)

}

@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [
            AppModule::class
        ]
    )
    abstract fun bindLibraryActivity(): LibraryActivity
}

@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(application: Application) = application as Context

}
```

What I've missed?

Comment: Have you added [`@ContributesAndroidInjector`](https://dagger.dev/api/2.12/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html) for `LibraryActivity` in app module? Have you enabled `kotlin-kapt` plugin in your library module?

Comment: You do not have to create `AppComponent` in library module, it must exist only in app module.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect `ActivityBuilder` module to component in app module, generally to root component (presumably `AppComponent` in you case). Probably you do not need to have any explicitly defined component in library module.

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindLibraryActivity(): LibraryActivity
}
```

Root component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityBuilder::class,
    ....
    ]
)
interface AppComponent { ... }
```

`AppComponent` shouldn't implement `AndroidInjector` interface. You must extend `android.app.Application`  and make your custom application class to implement `HasAndroidInjector` interface for injection to work.

Read this [page](https://dagger.dev/android) for better understanding and usage example.